# debugger for developpement PHP extention's

Tags: php, c, debugging, php-extension, zend-studio

I m starting developping a php extension based on C and the zend Api.

I m looking for a debugger which I can use for this.

I found a extension called 'Zend Debugger' but I m not sure if it's related to debugging php codes of web apps or related to debugging c code of php extensions.

Any informations about this will help me a lot.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Zend Debugger is for PHP code / opcodes for sure. For extension code you need your favorite 'real' debugger, e.g. I'm using gdb with ddd as GUI frontend on Linux for this ...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I understand there is no specific debugger for developping php extension's, but we can use the standard debugger on linux which is gdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use gdb to debug PHP extension. You can set breakpoint by function name, gdb will show you something like this because PHP extensions are loaded by `dlopen`. Press `y`, then `run`:

```
Function "foo" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

Comment: As I understand there is no specific debugger for developping php extension's, but we can use the standard debugger on linux which is gdb